# How to change a pointer to point to a different object?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a collection with values and I want to assign a pointer to point to one of the item in the collection.

Here is a similar example which does not work:

```
void changeVar(int * var) {
        int newInteger = 99;
        var = &newInteger;
}

int main() {
    // create a random pointer and initialize to NULL
    int * randomPointer= 0;

    // the printf prints out it's address as 0. good.
    printf("address: %d \n\r",  randomPointer);

    // pass the pointer to a function which should change where the pointer points
    changeVar(randomPointer);

    // the printf below should print the value of the newInteger and randomPointer should point to newInteger value address
    printf("value: %d \n\r", *randomPointer);

return 0;
}
```

How do I make so that after the changeVar function, the randomPointer points to the address of newInteger?

PS. `randomPointer` must be a pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a reference (a pointer to a pointer) to your function. In that way you can tell the function "change the value at this location".

```
void changeVar(int **pp){
  static int n=99;
  *p = &n;
}
```

Note - you need `static` because the memory location will otherwise be invalid once you leave the function. Now you call it with

```
changeValue(&randomPointer);
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the change to `var` propagate back to the caller, you need to pass `var` by pointer:

```
void changeVar(int** var) {
        (*var) = ...;
}
```

That said, `newInteger` goes out of scope the moment `changeVar` returns, so you shouldn't keep pointers to it after that. Dereferencing such a pointer would result in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: yes. i gave a bad example. in the real case, the object is static